# Nodejs, require module from within a function, or at top of script. Which is better for custom modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I'm writing a custom script which contains all my common used settings and functions. One of these functions takes a timestamp and returns a human readable date with a custom format using Moment.

My custom script is in the `node_modules` folder and the file is called `settings.js` for example. Now, I know I can include this at the top of any of my scripts using

`var settings = require('settings.js);`

and get my function by

`settings.timestamp_to_date(timestamp,function(date){console.log(date})`

What I don't know is the best place to include the additional modules (moment, and moment-timezone). I have them in the function call now so that they don't load on every single app requiring the `settings.js` file. My thought here is that it won't load that module into memory for apps that don't need it.

This has me wondering though, for apps that might use this function a lot, it'd be requiring the modules every single time the function is ran, which itself seems like a poor choice.

Which is the best option to accomplish what I'm after by having all my functions in a single file, and loading the required modules for the function only when the certain app needs it?

If it means in each app I have to declare which modules I'll want to use before including `settings.js` then that's not ideal. My apps so far are just learning apps for myself. Nothing I create currently will be used by many people.

What's the best option for low use apps, and what's the best for apps that might get high use in a production environment?

Comment: We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

Comment: Good philosophy in general, thanks. I'm fairly new to node, and don't really know how these inefficiencies might grow (exponentially?) so in some cases it's worth optimizing.

Answer (score 4):

Found this by accident when searching out something else http://justbuildsomething.com/node-js-best-practices/#2

It lists a couple good reasons to load modules at the top of the included script vs in a function.

1. `Imagine you had a module that took 30 minutes to load, which is unreasonable, but just imagine. If that module is only needed in one route handler function it might take some time before someone triggers that route and Node.js has to require that module. When this happens the server would effectively be inaccessible for 30 minutes as that module is loaded. If this happens at peak hours several users would be unable to get any access to your server and requests will queue up.`
2. `If the module you require causes an error and crashes the server you may not know about the error for several days, especially if you use this module in a rarely used route handler. No one wants a call from a client at 4AM telling them the server is down.`

Answer (score 1):

First, regarding your concern on whether requiring the module inside the function would lead to poor performance, it is not a problem. As you can see on the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), everytime you require a module, it is cached. And any subsequent *require* call to that module will return the very same reference that was returned to the first call.

Now, I personally find it better to declare all your modules on the top of the file since it:

1. Makes it easier to know when you are requiring a module that has a bug (for example, crashes something)
2. Makes it easier for the reader to know all the dependencies of your module.